# Dirichlet series of multiplicative function as Euler product

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

Let $f$ be a multiplicative function such that there is a constant $C_1$ with $|f(n)| = O(n^{C_1})$. Suppose that for every prime number $p$ and all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have

$$f(p)f(p^{k}) = f(p^{k + 1}) + p^{z} f(p^{k - 1})$$

where $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is some constant. Show that there is some constant $C$ with

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^{s}} = \prod_{p} (1 - f(p)p^{-s} + p^{z - 2s})^{-1}$$

where convergence is given in $\Re(s) > C$.

I tried applying a proposition that if $f$ is multiplicative, then the Dirichlet series is given by

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^{s}} = \prod_p (1 + \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f(p^{m})}{p^{ms}}).$$

But I can't proceed from the above.

Also when $f$ is completely multiplicative, then

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^{s}} = \prod_p (1 - \frac{f(p)}{n^{s}})^{-1}.$$

However, I couldn't prove that $f$ is completely multiplicative and if I assume $f$ to be completely multiplicative, then I get some absurdity.

Comment: The coefficients of $(1 - f(p)p^{-s} + p^{z - 2s})^{-1}=\sum_{k\ge 0} g(k) p^{-sk}$ satisfy the equation, by induction you get that $f(p^k)-g(k)=0$.